# Excel VBA collect Dropbox badge information

Tags: excel, vba, dropbox, badge

I would like to avoid the conflicing copies Dropbox automatically will create if more than one person at the same time edit an Excel document.

Dropbox have made a smart "badge" with information popping up, if someone is opening the files while you have it open.

If you use VBA to open and save the documents, you might not see this information (especially not if you speed up the macro wiht displayalerts false).

Does someone here know how to make the VBA "ask" for this information? (would need the information to stop the user from saving the document).

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't an interface for querying this information, but we'll consider this a feature request.