# Dropbox badge for MS Access who is working on the same file

Tags: ms-access, dropbox, badge

My question is:
Is there a badge for MS Access files like this: https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2015/10/dropbox-badge-now-available/

And is it possible to collect Dropbox badge information with VBA as one of the notibles (Greg K) of Dropbox has mentioned 3 year ago.

> currently isn't an interface for querying this information, but we'll
>   consider this a feature request.

here: [Excel VBA collect Dropbox badge information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258044/excel-vba-collect-dropbox-badge-information)

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Imran Bhatti

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox Badge is supported for Word, Powerpoint, and Excel, but not Access. You can find more information here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/business/badge-overview
https://www.dropbox.com/help/business/badge-issues

Also, there still isn't an API for querying this information programmatically. We're continuing to track it as a feature request.